# Python random math's quiz generator program, need adjustments

Tags: python, windows, file, math

I am trying to change 3 things in my code.

1. Make 'Answers' match the same set of random.randomint's used for 'Questions'.
2. Give the user an option to choose a specific operator to use for the quiz instead of random operators.
3. For the subtraction operators, ensure the first operand is bigger than the second operand so the program doesn't give negative answers.

Any answers are appreciated.
Here is my code:

```
import random

print("Welcome to the maths quiz creator!")
CLASS = input("Please enter the class name: ")
NAME = input("Please enter your name: ")
NoofQ = int(input("How many questions for the quiz? "))
```

## <--FIRST FILE FOR QUESTIONS-->

```
output_file = open('{}_quiz.txt'.format(CLASS), 'w')
print("Class:", CLASS)
print("Teacher:", NAME)

output_file.write("Class: ")
output_file.write(CLASS)
output_file.write("\nTeacher: ")
output_file.write(NAME)

for question_num in range(1,NoofQ +1):
    ops = ['*','/','+','-']
    rand=random.randint(1,12)
    rand2=random.randint(1,12)
    operation = random.choice(ops)
    maths = eval(str(rand) + operation + str(rand2))
    Questions = '\n {}: {} {} {} {} {}'.format(question_num, rand, operation, rand2, "=", "________")

    print(Questions)
    output_file.write(Questions)
output_file.close()
```

## <--SECOND FILE FOR ANSWERS-->

```
output_file = open('{}_answers.txt'.format(CLASS), 'w')
print("Class:", CLASS)
print("Teacher:", NAME)

output_file.write("Class: ")
output_file.write(CLASS)
output_file.write("\nTeacher: ")
output_file.write(NAME)

for question_num in range(1, NoofQ +1):
    ops = ['*','/','+','-']
    rand=random.randint(1,12)
    rand2=random.randint(1,12)
    operation = random.choice(ops)
    maths = eval(str(rand) + operation + str(rand2))
    Answers = '\n {}: {} {} {} {} {}'. format(question_num, rand, operation, rand2, "=", int(maths))

    print(Answers)
    output_file.write(Answers)
output_file.close()
```

I am fairly new to Python, writing with the program Pycharm.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: To ensure positive subtraction results you could use the [`abs` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs). Or you could [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) the values first : `small, big = sorted((4,3)); big - small`.

Comment: Do you want to keep the *questions* and *answers* code in separate files?

Comment: Yes the questions and answers are going to be in seperate files.
1st file just the random questions with blank spaces for the answer,
2nd file, same random questions with the answers included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Make 'Answers' match the same set of random.randomint's used for 'Questions'.

You could build one list first which creates the numbers and use it for questions and answers.

```
numbers = [(random.randint(1, 12), random.randint(1,12)) for _ in range(NoofQ)]
```

Then use it in questions and answers :

```
for question_num in range(1,NoofQ +1): #i would prefer that question_num starts at 0
    ops = ['*','/','+','-']
    rand, rand2 = numbers[question_num-1]
```

2 Give the user an option to choose a specific operator to use for the quiz instead of random operators.

```
op = input("Please enter your operator (+, -, /, or *): ")
```

3 For the subtraction operators, ensure the first operand is bigger than the second operand so the program doesn't give negative answers.

```
if operation == "-" and rand < rand2:
    rand, rand2 = rand2, rand
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I managed to get the same numbers produced with the 'Questions' and 'Answers'. But now the 'Answers' operators are different to the 'Question' operators, making the math's sum different in the answers file.
Any idea's?

Comment: @Nathan I'm sure you can adapt yourself the code I provided on the numbers for the operators. This is same logic.

Comment: I just managed to get it done, thank you so much @Corentin Limier for your help.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure positive subtraction results you could use the [abs function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#abs). Or you could [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) the values first :

```
answer = abs(4-3)
small, big = sorted((4,3))
answer = big - small.
```

You make a `xyz_quiz.txt` file that has all the information you need for the *answers* code.  Read the quiz file and for each question, use [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) methods to split and strip till you get the *math*.

```
>>> question = '1: 6 - 11 = ________'
>>> question, _ = question.split('=')
>>> question
'1: 6 - 11 '
>>> q_number, q = question.split(':')
>>> q_number
'1'
>>> q
' 6 - 11 '
>>> q = q.strip()
>>> q
'6 - 11'
>>>
```